# Migrating from custom web server to apache web server

Tags: java, apache

We had our own custom web server(written in java) built in 2005. We are thinking of moving to apache web server. Does anyone know any pointers about this process?

Comment: Depends on what you're running on it.

Comment: VTC/Belongs on serverfault.  This isn't a programming question, it's a server config question.

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) might be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: find everything about apache at http://www.apache.org/

Comment: I wonder when web server have been part of real servers. This may not be exactly programming question, but this is also not server fault question.

Comment: @yogsma: Server administration is just as much about server software as it is about server hardware, the O.S., etc.  A server without software is just a paper weight.  It's perfectly within the scope of Server Fault (though it's kind of a subjective, open-ended question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your code base in? If it's also in java then you will need a middle layer to actually run your applications, like tomcat.

Why do you want to move to apache. For a java code base you will be adding a layer of complexity. However, if you current server is broken or not scalable then by all means switch.

Here is an article on setting up tomcat and apache.

http://www.jajakarta.org/tomcat/tomcat3.2-4.0/tomcat-3.2.3/doc/tomcat-apache-howto.html